# Помогите написать SQL запрос с расчетом необходимых метрик

Tags: sql, запрос, метрики

Клиент: Омега

Категории:

- Потребительское кредитование (Целевой СРА 320р ),
- РКО (Целевой СРА 5000р)
- Период для анализа: июн - июль – авг 2020

Задача

- собрать единый датасет для анализа (sql запрос с расчетом необходимых метрик)

На вход 3 таблицы (Direct, Display, Dict - словарь соответствия "Клиент" = client_id)

Описание колонок:

- Client_id – идентификатор клиента
- Device – тип устройства
- Type – тип канала
- Place – тип площадки (только для Type: Direct)
- AdType – тип кампании (контекст, медийная) – только для Type: Direct
- QueryType – тип запроса (только для Type: Direct , только поиск)
- TargetingType – тип таргетинга (только для Type: Direct)
- direct_conv_visits_last_significant – целевые визиты (только Директ)

P.S. В excel я посчитал основные метрики CR, CPL, CPA, точки роста и т.д., но как это через sql посчитать не пойму. Хотя бы метрику CR

Comment: У вас что в excel, что в sql должна быть формула для расчета...

Comment: мне в sql не хватает опыта, можете подсказать как там формулу написать хотя бы CR рассчитать ?

Comment: в excel я через сводные таблицы посчитал

Comment: Как вы считали? Без разницы сводные, не сводные.. Всегда есть формула. cr это обычно простые переходы к действиям, нет?

Comment: я тут кое что набросал, посмотрите:

Comment: нужен sql запрос из 2 таблиц (direct и dict) по client_id 
с фильтром по 3 определенным месяцам (июн - июль – авг 2020)
с фильтром по 2 категориям (Потребительское кредитование и РКО)
и в запросе нужно рассчитать:
CR = клики/показы*100,
CPL = расходы/показы,
CPA = расходы/клики

Comment: select
    count(distinct dr.client_id), cr, cpl, cpa  
from 
    direct dr
    join dict dc on  dr.client_id = dc.client_id 
were
    month =  '01.06.2020' and '01.07.2020' and '01.08.2020'
    category = "ПОТРЕБИТЕЛЬСКОЕ КРЕДИТОВАНИЕ" and "РАСЧЕТНО-КАССОВОЕ ОБСЛУЖИВАНИЕ"
group by 
     dr.client_id
order by
    count(distinct dr.client_id)

Comment: спасибо за логику, запрос составил, задачу решил